# Gallery is not showing after uploading into live site using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below I am calling my gallery using Datalist in localhost gallery is showing and live site not showing.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#cube">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" class="cubeHide" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "/GalleryImages/{0}") %>' />
                    </a>
                        <div class="label_text">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Images are not loading? if this is so then confirm about path used for Images `../GalleryImages/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Change `ImageUrl` from this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "/GalleryImages/{0}") %>'
```

To this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/GalleryImages/{0}") %>'
```

2.Make sure you have a folder called GalleryImages in the root of your website with the relevant image files.

Answer (score 0):

I added simply **~** then resolve my issue:

```
 ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageName", "~/GalleryImages/{0}") %>'
```